# Missing item in map error

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I have defined a map and in a entry point i try to verify if the value of a key exists or not. I am getting error : Missing item in map: 'param' is not in {} while evaluating self.data.links[params]. This error is from the sp.verify(self.data.links[link] == True) line. As the map doesn’t contains a key 'link' it is giving this error.
Is there any way to call sp.verify(self.data.links[link] == True) even if there is no existing key.

```
class Test(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_initial_storage(
            links=sp.map(tkey=sp.TString, tvalue=sp.TBool))

    @sp.entry_point
    def remove(self, link):
        sp.verify(self.data.links[link] == True)
        del self.data.links[link]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No need to check if a key exists before deleting it.
- To check if a map contains a key you have the `.contains(key)` instruction. Example: `sp.verify(self.data.links.contains(link))`